# Why not give the old Klingons ridges?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon

The episode "[Trials and Tribble-ations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trials_and_Tribble-ations_%28episode%29)" had the DS9 cast interacting with TOS footage. When Sisko and company are surprised to see smooth-headed Klingons, Worf hints at some embarrassing racial secret which later leads to contrived attempts in later works to explain the disparity.

Seeing as they were already changing the original footage anyway, couldn't DS9's FX people have altered the old footage to give the early Klingons forehead ridges? Seems to me that would've saved a lot of hassle in the long run.

Comment: Personally, I thought DS9's lampshaded non-explanation was far more entertaining than any actual explanation would have been.

Comment: They probably wouldn't have wanted to anyway, but I don't really agree with the premise that it would have been relatively easy to add ridges, at least not without substituting modern actors for the original Klingon actors. Adding photorealistic CG bumps to an actor's head and having them track their head motions seamlessly *might* be doable with 1996 effects technology, but at the time I'd guess it'd be the sort of thing that would require a movie-level budget, not a TV episode budget.

Comment: It may be worth noting that only Bashir, O'brien, and Odo are surprised.  Bashir should know better but the other two could be reasonably expected not to care about 100 year old trivia.  But the joke is they are an audience proxy and this was the first time it was made absolutely clear TOS looked exactly like it really was.  (Note even TNG Romulans have small make-up differences one would be expected to think were always there)

Comment: Why not colorize the first five minutes of _The Wizard of Oz_?

Answer (score 25):

They likely could have, but I imagine they left it alone on purpose.

For starters, that is one of the most beloved episodes of the original series; messing with the original footage at all would likely not have gone over well with fans.

But beyond that, I suspect they were using it as a chance to clear the issue up.  Ever since the first time we see Worf on *The Next Generation*, his features had been a matter of debate among Star Trek fans. The fact that original-series-era Klingons did not look anything like Klingons from subsequent shows was left unexplained, at least in-universe.

The idea of some sort of genetic engineering or similar explanations had been floating around unofficially for many years. In that particular episode of DS9, the writers decided to finally address the question on-screen. Though they didn't really *explain* anything, we at least got confirmation that the change in appearance was canonical. Unfortunately, we would have to wait until [*Enterprise*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Affliction_(episode)) to get the full story

Comment: Seems more like lampshading it than addressing it to me. :-)

Comment: Mike,  bumpy headed Klingons appeared in the movies before TNG.

Comment: Yes, the Klingons in *The Motion Picture* had ridges although they [don't quite look like later Klingons](https://vincentpaone.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/themotionpicture0026.jpg), but the ones in *The Search For Spock* look [very similar](http://136589870a6a35f2061a-300fd00344af618df2fc22640adefd09.r37.cf1.rackcdn.com/splash/10-2013/SEARCH_FOR_SPOCK_SCREENSHOT_1.png) to TNG era Klingons.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - If you see small typos, don't post a comment, just correct them. Not only is it fun & useful, but you also get points for doing it!

Comment: @Richard: I'm fairly sure that you can't make single-character edits until you get edit privilege at 2000 points?  (But in any case I wasn't certain of Mike's intent.)

Comment: @harryjohnaton - I'm sure you could find six characters to improve :-)

Comment: “it might have been nice to be more definitive about it” — this theory has been [conclusively](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Affliction_(episode)) [disproven](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Divergence_(episode)).

Comment: They were *already* messing with the original footage, and if they had given the Klingons ridges there wouldn't be an issue to clear up- yeah I know it's taken me this long to say something.

Comment: @Nu'Daq I question whether the CGI of 1996 would have been able to make the original Klingons look like TNG-era Klingons in a convincing manner. They *could* have edited it, but I believe it would have been very noticeable.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I choose to think of the TMP klingons as a racial variation.  It's a shame DS9 never featured any as that's the last entry in my head canon.

Comment: @Xantec considering it seemed a bit novel to replace the face of an obvious stunt double in blade runner final cut (2007) I'm confident it was intractable for a tv budget of 1996 to have forehead ridges motion captured on the TOS klingons.   That could be a cellphone app now!
 Even the Tron sequel was in uncanny Valley  and that was 2010.  Though to be fair to everything but the flashback CLU2 was a computer character so it's ok.

Comment: @lucasbachmann As a modern analogue I was thinking of them digitally removing Henry Cavil's mustache in Justice League.

Comment: One thing no one has mentioned as far as I see here -- the storyline of that TOS episode depended on the Klingon *passing as human*.  With those ridges, the storyline would not have worked at all.

Comment: @Basya Klingons can presumably surgically alter themselves to pass for human as easily as a human can be altered to pass for Romulan.  This was well established in TOS and everything after so there's nothing to discuss.   A Klingon like Koloth would need very little change.  Kang's skin tone was a bit more exotic however.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Star Trek: Discovery demonstrates this

Comment: @OrangeDog Discovery needs a Rick &Morty level of surgery to turn a klingOrc into a human.  https://youtu.be/CdGKfBir7bI TOS just would need a skin color adjustment and a TNG klingon would need a skullplate removed.  So no Discovery is not relevant to TOS/TNG. "This involved traumatic surgery, including the flaying of his skin and sawing his heart into pieces. His limbs were opened up and his Radius, femurs and even his Spinal cord were shortened. The tips of his fingers were shaved down, his bones cracked open and crushed. " https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/ChoH%27a%27

Comment: @lucasbachmann because they did a full transformation, not just external appearance.

Answer (score 7):

The plot of the TOS episode, *The Trouble with Tribbles*, actually depends on the fact that a Klingon looks similar enough to humans to be disguised as one.

Towards the end of the episode, it is revealed that  Arne Darvin, an assistant of undersecretary Nilz Baris, is a Klingon disguised as a human.  In this position he was perfectly positioned to poison the grain on the station.  This was initially revealed by a tribble who squawked when this assistant entered the room (it was scientifically verified thereafter).

Thus, there would be a problem with retroactively adding the forehead ridges -- how could he have passed for human, with such a different facial structure?

So they might not have wanted to do this.  It would have damaged the plot line of the original episode.

Valorum pointed out in the comments that we see in Discovery that it's possible to surgically modify a Klingon (with ridges) to look like a human.  However, Discovery came out many years after *Trials and Tribble-ations*, so this is unlikely to have been a consideration when the DS9 episode was created.

Comment: We see in Discovery that it's possible to surgically modify a Klingon (with ridges) to look like a human

Comment: @Valorum -- I never saw that series.  Was it possible in the TOS era?

Comment: Yup. It actually predates the episode by a few years

Comment: Could they also put the ridges back?  Add them to someone who did not have them?

Comment: It would appear so. We don't see them doing it, but the character goes into the operation seems to be doing so with his eyes open and with the expectation of recovering his old life once his mission is complete

Comment: @Valorum - OK, I have added that into my answer, with a response.

Comment: Discovery barely respects the canon anyway...

Comment: One need not resort to Discovery.  The syndication audience of the 1970s would have been well aware of human to Romulan cosmetic surgery from the later Enterprise Incident.  If a Klingon had any in-universe subtle differences that wasn't obvious on a 1960s TV screen the audience would expect it could be surgically addressed.  The twist is that cosmetic surgery can't alter biochemistry and a Tribble will always sneeze at a Klingon.  In fact given the voodoo involved in Discovery's alteration process it is not clear that would still be the case and is actually a bad example.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I didn't think it was that obvious -- adjusting ears and eyebrows looks to me like much less invasive than changing the structure of the face.

Comment: Surgery was done in the TNG episode "First Contact" to turn Riker intro an alien species.  I imagine that many Klingons of means went through a procedure to restore their ridged appearance.  A procedure called a he.......uh, better not.